# Functional of higher order derivatives

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Optimization of functionals derived from the Euler-Lagrange equations is often phrased in terms of integrating a function $F$ of $x, \ f(x), \ f'(x).$ However, what if your differential form contains higher order derivatives such $f''$ or $f'''$?